# Trying to display Display an Index of Admin Users in Ruby on RailsError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

I've completed the Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial (for Rails 3)

I'm trying to get a list of all the admin users on a page at localhost:3000/users/admins however I'm getting an error when I go to the page admins. I also have a list of all users under the page localhost:3000/users
The error I'm getting is the following:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
>   Couldn't find user with id=admins
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in 'show'
>   Parameters:
>   {"id"=>"admins"}

In the rails console I'm able to call the user admin attribute with the line `admins = User.where(:admin => "t")`

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @title = @user.name
    @admins = User.where(:admin => "t")
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to University Sports!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @title = "Edit user"
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  #def admins
  #  @users = User.admins
  #  render "users/index"
  #end

  def admins
    @admins=User.where(:admin => "t")
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end  

  private

    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
FinalProject::Application.routes.draw do
  get "club/new"

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :users do
    collection do
      get :admins
    end
  end

  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  get "sessions/new"

  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

  match '/sign_up', :to => 'pages#sign_up'

  root :to => 'pages#home'

  resources :users
  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed   
    has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id", :class_name => "Relationship", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower

    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :name,    :presence   => true, :length  => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email,   :presence   => true, :format  => { :with => email_regex }, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

    scope :admins, where(:admin => true)

    # Automatically create the virtual attribute 'password_confirmation'.
    validates :password, :presence  => true, :confirmation  => true, :length  => { :within => 6..40 }
        before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil  if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
  end

  def following?(followed)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed)
  end

  def follow!(followed)
    relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(followed)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed).destroy
  end

  def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
  end

  private

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end



end
```

**admins.html.erb**

```
<ul class="admins">
  <%= render @admins %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to create a manual path in your routing file for /users/admins. The problem is that Rails has already configured a route for (GET)/users/**** to route straight to UsersController#show because you may usually want to perform a show on a User id (for example /users/222).

Try

```
match '/users/admins',  :to => 'users#admins'
```

Comment: It was coming up with the same thing. I changed it from 'users/admins' to just '/admins' and it's work, thanks for you help.